# JQuery: trigger() not calling related target

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick, radio-button

I have used the `trigger()` for checking the radio button after loading all the page content as the radio button value is coming from third party api.

I have make one option checked by default. So I used `trigger()` event for checking the radio button. The radio button have also it's click event.

In my code only radio button get selected but event is not firing.
my code is...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#btn_03").attr('checked', 'checked');

    jQuery("#btn_03").trigger("change");

    jQuery(".class input[type='radio']").live("change", function($) {
        alert("clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide your html code

Comment: you need to create change event using `#btn_03` . then it will work

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign the event handler before you trigger the event.

When you are actually triggering the event, you still haven't attached any listeners for that event. You are doing that in the next line. Thus the event `change` does get triggered but nothing happens on that event.

You can do it this way

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery("#btn_03").attr('checked', 'checked');

    jQuery(".class input[type='radio']").on("change", function($) {
        alert("clicked");
    });

    jQuery("#btn_03").trigger("change");
});
```

Also use "on" to bind events instead of "live" as per the latest jQuery documentation

Answer (score 3):

You need to trigger event *after* you attach event handler:

```
jQuery(".class input[type='radio']").on("change", function(e) {
    alert("clicked");
});

jQuery("#btn_03").prop('checked', true).trigger("change");
```

Also use `$.fn.on` instead of long time ago deprecated `$.fn.live`. And it's better to set `checked` property instead of attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook the change event before you actually call the change event. I've included a fiddle of the functionality you requested.

I've changed the change-event target to be the actual radio input since I did not have your html, but normally you would most likely want to use the name of the radio group to hook the event to, since those are usually coupled with a single behaviour - like so `$("input[name='radioName']").change(function(){ // Change event code });`

Sidenote: You can use '$' instead of of 'jQuery' to start an expression.

http://jsfiddle.net/du58fo3t/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn_03").attr('checked', true); // Check radio button

  // Hook change event on radio button
  $("#btn_03").change(function() {
    alert("clicked");
  });

  // Trigger change on radio button
  $("#btn_03").trigger("change");
});
```